# Connection closed in AKS with Nginx ingress

Tags: nginx, azure-aks

I have an AKS cluster using Nginx ingress controllers, and I infrequently but reliably receive errors like this:

- The connection was closed unexpectedly
- An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to these errors in the documentation at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jpsanders/2009/01/07/you-receive-one-or-more-error-messages-when-you-try-to-make-an-http-request-in-an-application-that-is-built-on-the-net-framework-2-0, which says:

> Also check and ensure the Keep-Alive timeouts on the server, load
>   balancer and client (.NET) are set so that the client is set to less
>   than the load balancer, which in turn is set less than the server.

In my case I needed to increase the `upstream-keepalive-timeout` setting to something larger than the default timeout of an Azure loadbalancer (which is 4 minutes). I set the value to 300 seconds, and the errors went away.

Edit

I also had to see the worker-shutdown-timeout value, as described in https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/3039.